# Python + HTML Submit button disappears with hidden form variable

Tags: python, html, css

I have an input with submit button in python and html it doesn't do anything yet, but when I add another hidden form value to use to store a variable the submit button disappears. Can anyone explain why?

The button is there with this code -

```
#! /usr/bin/python
print 'Content-type: text/html'
print ''

import cgi
import random
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

if "guess" in form:
    guess = form.getvalue("guess")
else:
    guess = ""

if "answer" in form:
    answer = form.getvalue("answer")
else:
    answer = ""
    for i in range(4):
        answer += str(random.randint(0,9))

print answer

print '<h1>Mastermind</h1>'
print '<form>'
print '<input type="text" name="guess" value="' + guess + '">'
print '<input type="hidden" name="answer" value="' + answer + '">'
print '<input type="submit" value="Guess!">'
print '</form>'
```

But disappears if I add another with a value of 'numberOfGuesses'

```
#! /usr/bin/python
print 'Content-type: text/html'
print ''

import cgi
import random
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

if "guess" in form:
    guess = form.getvalue("guess")
else:
    guess = ""

if "answer" in form:
    answer = form.getvalue("answer")
else:
    answer = ""
    for i in range(4):
        answer += str(random.randint(0,9))

print answer

print '<h1>Mastermind</h1>'
print '<form>'
print '<input type="text" name="guess" value="' + guess + '">'
print '<input type="hidden" name="answer" value="' + answer + '">'
print '<input type="hidden" name="numberOfGuesses" value="' + numberOfGuesses + '">'
print '<input type="submit" value="Guess!">'
print '</form>'
```

Comment: More likely: your program is running into an exception, because ``numberOfGuesses `` is undefined.

Comment: @MikeScotty Perfect, thanks. You should make an answer for me to tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that your button is disappearing, it's rather that your program is running into an exception, because `numberOfGuesses` is undefined.

To fix this, you simply have to define `numberOfGuesses` somewhere in our code before you access it.

```
numberOfGuesses  = "42"

print '<h1>Mastermind</h1>'
print '<form>'
print '<input type="text" name="guess" value="' + guess + '">'
print '<input type="hidden" name="answer" value="' + answer + '">'
print '<input type="hidden" name="numberOfGuesses" value="' + numberOfGuesses + '">'
print '<input type="submit" value="Guess!">'
print '</form>'
```